# add a class to first element in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, class

I have a simple question about jQuery array elements...

```
<div id="holder">       
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
var klassenarray = $("#holder").find("[class]").map(function() {
     return this.className;
   }).get();
alert(klassenarray);
```

Gives me:

```
A,A,A,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,C,C
```

Now I need to add a class called first to every element with the same className. Like that:

```
<div id="holder">       
    <div class="A first">A</div>
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B first">B</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C first">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: i don't know how to "catch" the first element of the class names in the array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can take your array, get the unique values, then loop through it and use the `first()` method to retrieve only the first elements with the given class. Try this:

```js
var klassenarray = $("#holder").find("[class]").map(function() {
  return this.className;
}).get();

$.unique(klassenarray).forEach(function(c) {
  $('.' + c).first().addClass('first');
});
```

```css
.first { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this :

```
$(".A:first").addClass('first')
$(".B:first").addClass('first')
$(".C:first").addClass('first')
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/248jvtwd/)

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of the logic in the question, ie. the class names are not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var previousClazz="";
            $("#holder > div").each(function(index,item){

                if(previousClazz==$(item).attr("class")){

                }else{
                    previousClazz=$(item).attr("class");
                    $(item).attr("class",$(item).attr("class")+" first")
                };
            });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!